# React Native Error: Element Type is Invalid

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need some help looking for where to start with this error I'm getting. Nimbus is the name of my app but I'm not sure what it means when it says `check the render method of 'Nimbus'`. Which render method? I have a functional component at `app/index.js` called Nimbus but obviously that doesn't render anything just returns a component.

I've checked similar error messages for RN on here and most people are just forgetting to export a component properly but I've checked my components and all are being exported correctly from what I can tell. The repo is below if you want to take a look at my project structure, etc. There are only a few files right now. Sorry I can't provide more information that's all I've got right now.

https://github.com/MaxwellGover/Nimbus

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the AppContainer is a default export:

```
export default class AppContainer ...
```

And you proxy it from the containers/index.js like this:

```
export { AppContainer } from  './App/AppContainer'
```

This tries to import a named export called `AppContainer`. Instead, you'll need to import the `default` export explicitly:

```
export { default as AppContainer } from  './App/AppContainer'
```

Comment: Ok. I'll check that out. Before I was exporting like `export AppContainer from './App/AppContainer` (so without `{ }`) and importing like `import { AppContainer } from '~/containers'` but this was throwing me some weird error. Is `export { default as someComponent }` the ideal way to handle exports then?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the only (?) syntax to take a default export of one module, and export it as a named export. Honestly I'm not sure whether the indirection you are applying in your sample codebase is worth the effort. If it grows large, then sure! But at small size, having the index files seems like unnecessary indirection.

Answer (score 1):

in your `index.js` you need to import component.

change following.

```
import { NimbusNavigator } from  './Navigator/NimbusNavigator'
import { SplashContainer } from './Splash/SplashContainer'
import { AppContainer } from  './App/AppContainer'
```

Comment: I'm using `babel-root-import` so I add exports to `containers/index.js` so I can import them into other components as needed like `import { AppContainer } from '~/containers` so not sure if the above is correct in my instance.

Comment: have u fix your issue with above answer?